# Create a row based on data from two rows

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I've looked at previous questions that were similar but I could not find this exact scenario.  I'm NOT trying to concatenate the data from two rows into one.  I'm trying to build a row based on data from two rows.  I'm not sure if this is something that can be done with a built in oracle function or it would need to be a custom one.  Using this table below as an example.

```
create table reporttable( Location varchar2(10), Manager varchar2(10), ManagerType varchar2(1), User_Id Number, Region varchar2(10)); 

insert into reporttable select USA, 'Robert', 'A', '123', 'East'  from dual;
insert into reporttable select USA, 'Unknown', 'A', '123', 'Unknown'  from dual;
commit;

  Location  Manager     ManagerType  User_Id Region 
        USA Robert             A      123    Unknown
        USA Unknown            A      123    East
```

The desired output i'd want is this because the **ManagerType** and **User_Id** indicates it's the same Manager

```
Location  Manager     ManagerType  User_Id Region 
      USA Robert             A      123    East
```

Comment: If any of the rows does not have matching 'not unknow' entry, would you like it to be displayed?

Comment: Yes, there could be a case where there's a row that does not have a matching managerType/User_Id in another row. In that case, I would need the row to be displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to update all the duplicates to keep only one row and delete the others and that the `manager` and `region` values being kept should be the maximum non-Unknown value then you can use:

```sql
MERGE INTO reporttable dst
USING (
  SELECT rowid AS rid,
         COALESCE(
           MAX( DECODE( manager, 'Unknown', NULL, manager ) ) OVER (
             PARTITION BY location, user_id, managertype
           ),
           'Unknown'
         ) AS manager,
         COALESCE(
           MAX( DECODE( region, 'Unknown', NULL, region ) ) OVER (
             PARTITION BY location, user_id, managertype
           ),
           'Unknown'
         ) AS region,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY location, user_id, managertype
           ORDER BY ROWNUM
         ) AS rn,
         COUNT(*) OVER (
           PARTITION BY location, user_id, managertype
         ) AS cnt
  FROM   reporttable
) src
ON ( src.rid = dst.ROWID AND src.cnt > 1 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET manager = src.manager,
      region  = src.region
  DELETE WHERE src.rn > 1;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
create table reporttable(
  Location varchar2(10),
  Manager varchar2(10),
  ManagerType varchar2(1),
  User_Id Number,
  Region varchar2(10)
);
insert into reporttable
select 'USA', 'Robert', 'A', '123', 'East'  from dual union all
select 'USA', 'Unknown', 'A', '123', 'Unknown'  from dual;
```

Then after the `MERGE` then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM reporttable;
```

Outputs:

> | LOCATION | MANAGER | MANAGERTYPE | USER_ID | REGION |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | USA | Robert | A | 123 | East |

---

If you just want to `SELECT` from the table, then you can use the same method and just filter on the `ROW_NUMBER` within each partition:

```sql
SELECT location,
       manager,
       managertype,
       user_id,
       region
FROM   (
  SELECT location,
         COALESCE(
           MAX( DECODE( manager, 'Unknown', NULL, manager ) ) OVER (
             PARTITION BY location, user_id, managertype
           ),
           'Unknown'
         ) AS manager,
         managertype,
         user_id,
         COALESCE(
           MAX( DECODE( region, 'Unknown', NULL, region ) ) OVER (
             PARTITION BY location, user_id, managertype
           ),
           'Unknown'
         ) AS region,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY location, user_id, managertype
           ORDER BY ROWNUM
         ) AS rn
  FROM   reporttable
) 
WHERE rn = 1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=01615801448c7381493cae52c2f784a1)*

Comment: One question, would this work if there are unique rows that have no other row with location, user_id and managertype that are duplicate?

Comment: @MSkiLLz You can try it and find out [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e07dcb822c71f267164b2b756e8bc816)